# Generate mobile apps using Cordova and webbrowser

Tags: jquery, cordova, browser

I'm new in working with Cordova.

I've got a question:
I'm looking for a way to generate mobile applications (Android, iOS, WinPhone7/8) out of the browser without using Netbeans or Eclipse.

A user should have the possibility to click a button on my website. After this my website creates all files (.apk and so on) from a pre-defined layout (by me). Now the user can download this .apk and so and can put them into each marketplace...

Is this way possible?
What do I need? (Cordova? jQuery-mobile? AngularJS?) 
I thought there's a way like http://build.phonegap.com for Apache Cordova.

My idea:
1) User clicks Button
2) My website creates a zip-archive by pre-defined layouts
3) My website calls for example http://build.mywebsite.com/?file=xyz.zip
4) My website returns a zip-file with .apk and so on

Thank you!

Greetz,
Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

Android: For android that might be possible if they give you the key to sign the apk with. You could just setup a bash script that runs on the server. Here is how you would create the apk from the command line http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

IOS: It is possible to create an IPA via the command line, but again, they would need to supply you with all the certs and everything. You probably would also have to do it from a mac, and they might also have to supply you with their developer login information. I honestly have never done it from the command line, though everyday I am tempted to use https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen

I have never published or built windows app, so I am not sure about that. You might have to use windows to do that.

After that its just a matter of setting a LAMP stack (or whatever you want) that would execute the commands and make the resulting files available for download. However, security would probably be a big issue with an application like this. Given the nature of this app, I would not keep anyones certificates or anything on the server, since there are probably exploits in the build process people could take advantage of if they uploaded the right files.